# Vue.js with babel (for IE9 compatablity), without node build step

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to make Babel-standalone and Vue.js works together, so it can be 
compatible with IE9 browser ? I'm going to use in plain html without any build step.

My fears that they are to different analyzers, but i want to apply them to single code block.

*The environment doesn't assume node.js build step.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue.js supports IE9 already. You don't need any build steps to use Vue with IE9, you just need to be sure that any additional code works on IE9 as well.

Comment: But what about .vue files ? The vue examples mention 'export' i.e. ES6 modularity. I think vue compiler doesn't convert ES6 to ES5 as Babel do.

Comment: It's possible to use Vue without using .vue files. If you want to use .vue files then a build step is the only reasonable way to go. However there are a lot of examples of people plugging Vue in on a script tag and it works perfectly fine.